# How to set up bitbucket when you have a project folder with previous .git files?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, pycharm

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu on my machine and made a backup of all files and folders. I am in the process of syncing my local files back with the repository on bitbucket using PyCharm. I have seen many tutorials on how to do this for a NEW repository, but I have seen none on how to do this if your project already exists PLUS you have existing .git files in the project.

I have already downloaded the bitbucket plugin, set up my remote, and tested the connection but I keep getting this error when I try to push files:

```
Commit failed with error:
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   Detection-alf/loadTrainingImages.py~
    modified:   automated-detection-for-alf/bibsmart_auto_detector.py~
    modified:   automated-detection-for-alf/bibsmart_verify_csv.py~
```

This is what I get if I do git push

```
alfredo@alfpc-ubuntu:~/Dropbox/Alfredo1/Caffe$ git push
Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': alfredox10
Password for 'https://alfredox10@bitbucket.org': 
To https://bitbucket.org/alfredox10/bibsmart_detection
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/alfredox10/bibsmart_detection'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I did git pull and tried again.

```
alfredo@alfpc-ubuntu:~/Dropbox/Alfredo1/Caffe$ git pull
Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

But I had to stash the changes.

```
alfredo@alfpc-ubuntu:~/Dropbox/Alfredo1/Caffe$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: df3e5e0 terminal git test commit
HEAD is now at df3e5e0 terminal git test commit
```

Finally I did git pull, to make my local files the same as those on the server.

```
alfredo@alfpc-ubuntu:~/Dropbox/Alfredo1/Caffe$ git pull
Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': alfredox10
Password for 'https://alfredox10@bitbucket.org': 
From https://bitbucket.org/alfredox10/bibsmart_detection
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto packing the repository for optimum performance. You may also
run "git gc" manually. See "git help gc" for more information.
Counting objects: 159251, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (159214/159214), done.
Writing objects: 100% (159251/159251), done.
Total 159251 (delta 15072), reused 0 (delta 0)
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream 24c9aac9a2eccf4313835cf89f7ece050e049d46
```

I did git push again, and I still get this now.

```
alfredo@alfpc-ubuntu:~/Dropbox/Alfredo1/Caffe$ git push
Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': alfredox10
Password for 'https://alfredox10@bitbucket.org': 
To https://bitbucket.org/alfredox10/bibsmart_detection
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/alfredox10/bibsmart_detection'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: I would just suggest doing it from the command line using the copy-paste instructions Bitbucket gives when you create a new project there through-the-web.

Comment: I did, still not luck.

Comment: The repository where you are pushing is not empty.

Comment: Indeed that is the problem. The repository has files, but I reinstalled Ubuntu and backed up those files, which are up to date locally. I just want to link my local files to the ones online, that's all. I want git to realize the files are identical, I just want to link the project again in PyCharm.

Comment: If the files are identical, just recreate a new repository from the scratch. That's easiest solution.

Comment: Yeah that's what ended up working, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add them these files first and the commit and push them:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Your commit message'
git push
```

However, from the file names I guess they are temp files, you you better delete and ignore them (in `.gitignore`):

```
*~
```

---

Also, like @MikkoOhtamaa commented, you can just create a new repository:

> If the files are identical, just recreate a new repository from the scratch. That's easiest solution. –  Mikko Ohtamaa 23 hours ago

Comment: I modified the post, tried some of what you told me, plus other stuff I found online.

Comment: @alfredox OK, we will do it step by step: what's the output of `git status` now?

Comment: > On branch master
> Changes not staged for commit:
>   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
>   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
> 
>  modified:   .idea/workspace.xml
> 
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
> alfredo@alfpc-ubuntu:~/Dropbox/Alfredo1/Caffe$

Comment: @alfredox OK, so do now `git add . -A` and then `git commit -m 'Saving work'` (or some relevant message). Then give send me `git status` output again or output of `git commit/add` if they failed.

Comment: @alfredox See the edit. Marking the answer would be appreciated. :) Thanks!!